# Should this question go here or somewhere else?

Tags: support, questions

I want to know what the first command-line interface was. That is, the first time one could type in a command with a keyboard and receive feedback via a screen or teleprinter, as opposed to entering commands via paper tape, etc.

Should this question go here, history of science and mathematics, or some other stack?

Comment: [T.E.D.'s right](http://meta.history.stackexchange.com/questions/2122/should-this-question-go-here-or-somewhere-else/2123#2123); we could rock it. On HSM, we have a [tag:computer-science] tag with 14 questions; 11/14 are answered. One of them, http://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/1905/who-created-the-first-vacuum-tube, is similar to yours (in the "who was first" sense). So we'll take it, if you decide to ask it there.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it would be on-topic here. We have a [computers](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/computers) tag. Of the on-hold/closed questions there, 2 were for being easily found trivia, and one was for being unclear. There's one more that has no answers and some discussion about other stacks on it, but I believe that was because the question was very technical. So if you can avoid those pitfalls, it ought to be OK here.

It would probably be on-topic on the HSM stack too. I'm not sure how good they are at answering history of computing questions there, but that's just ignorance on my part. For all I know, they could rock it.